# Numpy.split not working a list of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of 31 dataframes, `days`, of shapes (11122, 88) to (22123, 88) stored in a standard Python list (of overall shape (31, 1)). I want to call `train_x, test_x = np.split(days, [int(0.8*len(days))])` to split that list into two separate lists.

However, np.split() fails, saying `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 11122 to array axis with dimension 88`. This makes me thing np.split() is trying to operate on the dataframes inside the list, which is not what I want to do.

Calling `np.asarray(days)` also produces the same error.

Realistically, I could get around this by using regular Python list indexing `train_x = days[:int(0.8*len(days))]`, but I wanted to post this here in case I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: `split` just does a sequence of slices.  So if your own slicing works, it's just as good (and just as fast).

Comment: Thanks. I figured it's simpler to just use regular indexing anyways, but I'm still very curious as to why np.split() doesn't work:

`test_x = days[:int(0.8*len(days))]`
`train_x = days[int(0.8 * len(days)):]`

Comment: `np.split` is meant to work with an array, so if you give it a list, it will try, at some point to convert it.  It appears that your dataframes vary in size, so the resulting `np.array` either creates an object array, or fails with an error.  Most `numpy` functions convert a list argument into an array before working on it.